# Runtime Error in Dynamic Sized Character Array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  char c, *input;
  input = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

  if(input == NULL) {
    printf("NOT ENOUGH SPACE!");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Input a string, press ENTER when done: ");

  while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    realloc(input, (sizeof(char)));
    input[i++] = c;
  }

  input[i] = '\0';
  printf("\nYou've entered the string: %s\n", input);
}
```

The above code snippet works well for small input. But it fails whenever the input provided is of large size. Either there is a run time error or a segmentation error.
There may be some error in reallocation of memory space.
I basically want to store a character array dynamically from user, i.e without mentioning the capacity of the input the user can directly put in any size of character array.

Answer (score 2):

The logic here is wrong:

```
  while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
      realloc(input, (sizeof(char)));
      input[i++] = c;
  }
```

You're not actually increasing the size of the buffer, and you are also discarding the result of `realloc`.

Try:

```
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    // Note: you need one extra character for the terminator, so for the
    // first char, when `i` is 0, then you need room for two `char`s in
    // the buffer - one for the first input character and one for the
    // terminator. And so on...
    char * temp = realloc(input, i + 2); // NB: realloc can, and sometimes does, fail
    if (temp == NULL) // if realloc failed then exit program
        exit(1);
    input = temp;     // otherwise update input...
    input[i++] = c;
  }
```

---

Also, since you are always going to be calling realloc on every character (which is very inefficient, incidentally, but it works), this line:

```
input = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

(which should not have a cast, BTW, since this is C, not C++) can just be:

```
input = NULL;
```

---

And one final bug:

```
char c;
```

should be:

```
int c;
```

otherwise your `while` loop may never terminate, since `EOF` can only be properly represented as an `int`.

---

So the final fixed program should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int c;
    char * input = NULL;

    printf("Input a string, press ENTER when done: ");

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        // Note: you need one extra character for the terminator, so for the
        // first char, when `i` is 0, then you need room for two `char`s in
        // the buffer - one for the first input character and one for the
        // terminator. And so on...
        char * temp = realloc(input, i + 2); // NB: realloc can, and sometimes does, fail
        if (temp == NULL) // if realloc failed then exit program
            exit(1);
        input = temp;     // otherwise update input...
        input[i++] = c;
    }

    input[i] = '\0';
    printf("\nYou've entered the string: %s\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is great sir. But I am still getting a TLE.
After replacing this snippet 
_while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {_
     _ realloc(input, (sizeof(char)));_
     _ input[i++] = c;_
  _}_

with yours.

Comment: Did you apply all THREE bug fixes above ?

Comment: No basically I applied only the one in the while loop.
Should I apply all of them?

Comment: Um, think about it a minute - you have (at least) three bugs in your code - should you just fix one of the bugs, or should you fix all three ? (I've now added a complete, fixed, version of the code, above, for your convenience.)

Comment: Well.
All three. 
:D
Yea.
Now it's running smooth.
Thank You Sir.